# Laravel - Cardinality violation error in Aggregate Sum

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying a Query to get Current Day, Current Week, Current Month, Current Year and Total Sales. All together as one result. I used the Query shown below:

```
    $currentDay = date('d');
    $currentWeek = date('w');
    $currentMonth = date('m');
    $currentYear = date('y');

    $revenues = DB::table("vw_revenue_report")
->select(
    "vw_revenue_report.channel",
    DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN ('DAY(created_at) = ?',$currentDay) THEN amount ELSE 0 END) daily_revenue"),    
    DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN ('WEEK(created_at) = ?',$currentWeek) THEN amount ELSE 0 END) weekly_revenue"),
    DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN ('MONTH(created_at) = ?',$currentMonth) THEN amount ELSE 0 END) monthly_revenue"),
    DB::raw("SUM(CASE WHEN ('YEAR(created_at) = ?',$currentYear) THEN amount ELSE 0 END) yearly_revenue"),
    DB::raw("SUM(vw_revenue_report.amount) total_revenue")
)
->groupBy("vw_revenue_report.channel")
->orderByRaw('vw_revenue_report.channel ASC')
    ->get();
```

While trying to run it, I got the error shown below:

> "SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s) (SQL: select `vw_revenue_report`.`channel`, SUM(CASE WHEN ('DAY(created_at) = ?',02) THEN amount ELSE 0 END) daily_revenue, SUM(CASE WHEN ('WEEK(created_at) = ?',2) THEN amount ELSE 0 END) weekly_revenue, SUM(CASE WHEN ('MONTH(created_at) = ?',07) THEN amount ELSE 0 END) monthly_revenue, SUM(CASE WHEN ('YEAR(created_at) = ?',19) THEN amount ELSE 0 END) yearly_revenue from `vw_revenue_report` group by `vw_revenue_report`.`channel` order by vw_revenue_report.channel ASC, `vw_revenue_report`.`channel` asc limit 100 offset 0) ◀"

What do I do to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully it will work for you

```
$currentDay = date('d');
$currentWeek = date('w');
$currentMonth = date('m');
$currentYear = date('y');

$revenues = DB::table("vw_revenue_report")
->select(
    "vw_revenue_report.channel","sum(amount) as Total_in_day",
    DB::raw("(select sum(amount) as tot from vw_revenue_report where WEEK(created_at) = $currentWeek) as Total_in_week"),
    DB::raw("(select sum(amount) as tot from vw_revenue_report where MONTH(created_at) = $currentMonth) as Total_in_month"),
    DB::raw("(select sum(amount) as tot from vw_revenue_report where YEAR(created_at) = $currentYear) as Total_in_year")
)
->where("DAY(created_at)",$currentDay)
->get();
```

Comment: I got this error:       ErrorException (E_ERROR)
A non well formed numeric value encountered (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\bbnaijareport\resources\views\report\revenueReport.blade.php)

Comment: It is an error in your view file. Have you tried to print your result array? Is it expected or not?

Comment: Also remove format function and change "format((select...),2) as total_in_..."  to ("(select ...) as total_in_...")

Comment: Is it like this:      DB::raw("((select sum(amount) as tot from vw_revenue_report where DAY(created_at) = $currentDay),2) as daily_revenue"),

Comment: I've Edited my Answer check it out.

Comment: The issue now is that it populates the table rows and columns with the same data all through

Comment: object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#323 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(4) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#324 (6) { ["channel"]=> string(7) "9mobile" ["daily_revenue"]=> NULL ["weekly_revenue"]=> NULL ["monthly_revenue"]=> float(60) ["yearly_revenue"]=> NULL ["total_revenue"]=> float(1000) } [1]=> object(stdClass)#328 (6) { ["channel"]=> string(7) "GTB-737" ["daily_revenue"]=> NULL

Comment: ["weekly_revenue"]=> NULL ["monthly_revenue"]=> float(60) ["yearly_revenue"]=> NULL ["total_revenue"]=> float(2736) } [2]=> object(stdClass)#326 (6) { ["channel"]=> string(7) "UBA-919" ["daily_revenue"]=> NULL ["weekly_revenue"]=> NULL ["monthly_revenue"]=> float(60) ["yearly_revenue"]=> NULL ["total_revenue"]=> float(1052) } [3]=> object(stdClass)#329 (6) { ["channel"]=> string(10) "Unity-7799" ["daily_revenue"]=> NULL ["weekly_revenue"]=> NULL ["monthly_revenue"]=> float(60) ["yearly_revenue"]=> NULL ["total_revenue"]=> float(80) } } }

Comment: it is because you haven't applied any condition add condition in your main query for example if you like only today's data : ->where("DAY(created_at)",currentDay).

Comment: Where do I put the conditions. Then each of the four have its own condition and I want to display the result as:             store |  Today Sales  | This Week Sales  | This Month Sales  | This Year Sales

Comment: The error has changed to:    SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'DAY(created_at)' in 'where clause'